# Np.min in in 3d numpy array in swi.nii image(medical image)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, min

I want to calculate np.min for 3d numpy array ( swi.nii.gz medical image) but the result image is black because of the empty space in the source image,and I can't specify in the calculation of the np.min to consider non zero points as the minimum.
I calculated np.max easily.but np.min for 3d numpy array  is too difficult based on z-axis.

```py
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import glob


image_path = 'd:\img\swi.nii.gz'

# comment [load img by nibabel]
image_obj = nib.load(image_path)

image_data = image_obj.get_fdata()
print(f'type of images class={type(image_data)}')
print(image_data)

plt.title(os.path.basename(image_path))

# comment [plt.imshow(np.min(np.where(image_data>0,image_data,1), axis=2), cmap='jet')
# plt.imshow(np.min(np.ndarray.nonzero(image_data), axis=2), cmap='jet')]

plt.imshow(np.min(image_data>0, axis=2), cmap='jet')

plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[click here to see the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba5ui.png)

[while the output image should be this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFXc.png)

Comment: 1. Please don't post screenshots of your code but the actual code. 2. What do you mean when you say empty space? Can you create a dummy data set, maybe scaled down to a few pixels in each dimension?

Comment: 1_Sure, I will send you the code, 2_in medical image there are many pixel which are zero value 3_i can't create dummy data set, data set  is real (note: the code("(np.min(image_data,axis=2)cmap='jet')") work on any nii image like Tof.nii and .. except swi.nii image) ____ image_data is 3d numpy array

Comment: I completed the question and wrote the main code

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I *think* I know what you mean. With

> and I can't specify in the calculation of the np.min to consider non zero points as the minimum

do you mean to state that your algorithm should

> find the lowest pixel value which is not zero

?

If so, do it like this:

```py
minimum = np.min(image[image != 0])
```

EDIT: Your updated code makes it look like you want the minimum along a specific axis. This is an entirely different problem. Try this:

```py
minimum = np.ma.masked_equal(image, 0).min(axis=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still doesn't work, and the output image is black and with scattered  white dots

Comment: This code ib better and shows an image of the skull but does not yet clearly show the internal vessels.

Comment: @nazi okay at this point you are not asking me to fix your code but to fix your algorithm. That's not something I can do, especially not without input data (and even then this would be too much work). I suggest you read up on imaging algorithms for your kind of input data. I'm sure there are scientific papers on how to best visualize whatever you have. What is it anyway? PET, CCT, MRT?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think this algorithm is correct, because I do it on other medical images but it does not work on the swi.nii image (MRI). Anyway, thank you very much, and if a better solution comes to your mind, please tell me. Thank you very much

Comment: Excuse me, can you help me when we use np.ma.masked_equal (nparray, 0), this function replaces 0 with"--", so when we use np.min, "--" considers  as the minimum element So the output becomes false, while I want the minimum element to be non-zero and non"--" .

Comment: @nazi you can access the unmasked underlying data as masked.data. However, masked elements should not be considered by min. What could happen is that all elements along an axis are zero, then all become masked and min has no choice but return ```--```. You can replace masked values by calling ```filled```: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.filled.html#numpy.ma.filled

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, my problem is that I do not know what data to use instead of zero as the minimum number.